# Mounted function in vue js component is called continously when clicking anywhere on the page

Tags: vue.js

I have two vue js components in my page(eg:cart page).When I click anywhere on the page, these two components refreshed.(mounted function is called when the User interacts with the page).

Mounted function should be called only once when the page loads,but here it is called whenever user interacts with the page.

Comment: Can show an example of your code please - normally just the Vue file or html is enough if it contains the elements and JS code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.